# Consequences of allowing more than one Lore Sheet

Tags: house-rules, world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade-5e

It is my understanding that the core rules intention is that every PC have one and only one lore sheet.

What is the consequences of allowing a player to access more than one lore sheet? The things that I'm worried about are:

- Is the lore sheet advantages unbalanced so that by allowing one player to access more than one sheet he will get a significant advantage?
- Is the lore sheet advantages prone to grab the limelight, so that by allowing a player to access more than one sheet, he will get too much attention in play?

The best answer would be based on practical experience, but as this is a new game, I'm also happy to accept an answer based on analysis of the rules.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of both, but I believe it's more focused on the latter point.

Lore Sheets are a concept which have popped up in other games, and taking dots in one is meant to bring that general entity (person, organization, historical occurrence) into the campaign's story. I'm sure there are combinations of lore sheet dots which could be really overpowered, but by restricting to one per PC, you're making it easier for the GM to weave the Lore Sheet into the plot.